# How to merge rows in DataFrame according to unique elements and get averages?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve this. I'm trying to get the average `price` for each `day` and `hour` entries. So a DataFrame like

```
    day     hour    price   booked
0   monday  7      12.0     True
1   monday  8      12.0     False
2   tuesday 7      13.0     True
3   tuesday 8      13.0     False
4   monday  7      15.0     True
5   monday  8      13.0     False
6   tuesday 7      13.0     True
7   tuesday 8      15.0     False
```

should give something like:

```
    day     hour    avg. price  
0   monday  7       13 
1   monday  8       12.5    
2   tuesday 7       13.0 
3   tuesday 8       14.0
```

I would like this generalize to larger data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby the day and hour column and then call `mean` on the price column:

```
In [46]:

df.groupby(['day','hour'])['price'].mean()
Out[46]:
day      hour
monday   7       13.5
         8       12.5
tuesday  7       13.0
         8       14.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

To restore the day and hour back as columns you can call `reset_index`:

```
In [47]:

df.groupby(['day','hour'])['price'].mean().reset_index()
Out[47]:
       day  hour  price
0   monday     7   13.5
1   monday     8   12.5
2  tuesday     7   13.0
3  tuesday     8   14.0
```

You can also rename the column if you desire:

```
In [48]:

avg = df.groupby(['day','hour'])['price'].mean().reset_index()
avg.rename(columns={'price':'avg_price'},inplace=True)
avg
Out[48]:
       day  hour  avg_price
0   monday     7       13.5
1   monday     8       12.5
2  tuesday     7       13.0
3  tuesday     8       14.0
```